# Шейдер для 2д игры для сортировки объектов

Tags: c#, шейдеры, godot

Пишу 2д игру на godot. Но вопрос скорее не по движку, а по шейдерам вообще, а , возможно, и по С#. Проблема в том, что у меня рисуются крыши (это меши, которые рисуются за один проход - много polygon2d, помещенных в CanvasGroup). Мне крайне важно, чтобы они рисовались за один раз. Поэтому они рисуются поверх всего в сцене, в том числе поверх деревьев. Можно ли как-то хитро это исправить через шейдер ? То есть мне в шейдере нужна информация о глубине того, что уже отрендерено -  не просто цвет пикселя (Screen texture), а еще что-то. Возможно, стоит покопать в сторону постэффектов. Может что-то про двойной буфер (вот эта нода в годоте выглядит интересно BackBufferCopy). Но никак не могу сообразить как конкретно решить эту проблему. Мир меняется динамически, он огромный, поэтому заранее заготовленные текстуры не прокатят. Как бы так в шейдере определить рисовать пиксель крыши или там дерево ?

[image: скрин]

Comment: Обычно это решается сортировкой объектов по расстоянию от базы (места где объект (или вертикаль от него, в случае крыши) воткнут в землю) до нижнего края экрана.

Comment: @Kromster да, но тогда придется разбить крышу на тайлы и вытащить ее из CanvasGroup, мне нужен другой способ

Comment: Разбивка на тайлы не обязательна, и из группы что-то доставать в принципе тоже, если отрисовка не по группам пойдет, а будет в них "заходить".

Comment: @Kromster а как она может в них "заходить" ? У CanvasGroup в годоте именно такая фишка - все, что лежит внутри рисуется за один проход. Это используется и для производительности и для визуальных эффектов. Разве можно как-то сделать, чтобы движок частично брал оттуда полигоны для отрисовки ? Внутри группы сортировка есть, но поместить туда деревья тоже нельзя - потеряется смысл и эффект. Мне кажется должен быть способ через шейдер - для 3д используются же значения нормалей, например. Или есть параметр глубины для уже отрендеренного на экране, а не только цвет - как бы мне такое в 2д добавить

Comment: Про Godot не знаю, поэтому пишу в комментарии из общих соображений. Располагать по оси Z (глубине от камеры) нет возможности?

Comment: @Kromster сортировка по Y есть, и по Z тоже - так и сделаны все объекты на карте - они правильно перекрываются друг другом. Но крыша у меня рисуется после всего, поэтому не получится ее "честно" отсортировать

Comment: Значит выносите её из группы )